# Wireless Lapels / Group Conversation - Best settings to avoid Spill

Tags: audio-recording, wireless, sennheiser, lapel

---

Setting: 3 people, smallish room (no acoustic panels), screen recording a webinar, wireless lapel mics (Sennheiser ew100 g3)

---

[image: Webinar Recording Room]

What are recommended settings are for both TX and RX when lapel recording a group (3 people) in such a room.

Looking for settings that are clear enough to work with (eg: remove background noise, add limiter, bit of EQ), but also avoid spill from the voice of the person sitting next to them.

Currently using Transmitter -12dB Sensitivity / Receiver -12dB AF Out, which creates very similar audio waveforms in my NLE for all speakers in the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not transmitter/receiver settings that will allow you to control spill in a context such as this, it's simply a matter of where you place the mic. *Nothing* else will matter other than this. For minimum spill, you will need to get the mic as close as is practical to the source of the sound (i.e. mouth). With a senny Lav, you will probably be working on jackets or ties. Expect some spill. There's not a lot you can do about it other than move the mic. EQ and level settings won't have any impact on the relative signal/spill levels.

Comment: Correct – I'm positioning the mics an (extended fingers) hand-span from their mouths on jackets and ties.

Comment: Wondering if it's a valid strategy to drop the recording levels lower than optimal to avoid picking up the other people (as much as possible) and isolate the active speaker. Then 'recover' the active speaker to useable levels when editing?

Comment: Nope. Don't do this. It won't make any difference to the relative level ratio. All you will end up doing is recording less level overall and then you will have to post-produce it to fix up the recording. You'll just end up making the recording noisier.

Comment: One useful thing to consider is to separate the people a little more in order to improve separation. Remember that a doubling of the spill distance is a level reduction of 6dB. If person A is 2ft away from person B, then by making them 4ft apart, you decrease spill between A and B by 6dB.

Comment: Right - might flip that table horizontally, and perch them at each end with the moderator in the middle then. Thanks heaps.